# Chrome extension logic is not wοrking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've managed to get most of my Chrome extension working, but there is a problem I can't work out.

You can grab it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/tester) if you want and load it as an unpacked extension.

After loading it works like this.

1. You are prompted that they need to enter a URL on the options page.
2. You enter a URL (e.g. `http://example.com`) on the options page as asked and click save, and then when you click the icon in the toolbar you can see the web page appear in the popup.
3. If you then go and removes the URL from the options page and clicks save, then the popup does not show the original prompt page they saw at the beginning.

I think this code (from `popup.js`) is at fault, but I can't see why it won't work.

```
var url = localStorage.url;
var alturl = chrome.extension.getURL("need-to-enter-url.html");
var element = document.getElementById("testerURL");

if (url != undefined || url != null) {

element.src = url;

} else {

element.src = alturl;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "remove" the `url` you are actually saving an empty string. `localStorage.url = ""` so your value checking is failing. I would also recommend tweaking the if logic to be clearer.

Use something like this:

```
if (url === undefined || url === null || url === "") {
    element.src = alturl;
} else {
    element.src = url;
}
```

Optionally you can rely on [JavaScript's truthiness](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

```
if (url) {
    element.src = url;
} else {
    element.src = alturl;
}
```